# PHP File Manager Crashes When Reading Large Directory

Tags: php, file-management

It looks like scandir() is causing issues here and if i could set a depth limit it might work better, but im not too sure.

My website has a large images directory (25gb) that is very well organised. Im using tinyMCE with the file manager Roxy Fileman. When i try to load the root folder "images" it just keeps loading and eventually crashes. If i hardcode it to open "images/posts" it loads up fine. I have checked the source code and it looks like this function is doing the reading of directories.

```
function listDirectory($path){
  $ret = @scandir($path);
  if($ret === false){
    $ret = array();
    $d = opendir($path);
    if($d){
      while(($f = readdir($d)) !== false){
        $ret[] = $f;
      }
      closedir($d);
    }
  }

  return $ret;
}
```

One directory in particular contains about 99% of the images and i do not need to access this using the file manager, but i cannot move the directory either. "images/games" is the cause. Is there either a way for me to ignore this directory or only scan to a certain depth.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to read directories yourself, you could do so and create a list with ignored directories. You said that the directory `games` contained around 99% of the images, but you didn't need to access it. This could be a perfect candidate for a ignored directory.

If this is possible I would write something like the following:

```
function read_directory_files($path, array $ignored = []) {

    /*
     * Check if the provided path is readable and is a directory.
     */
    if(!is_readable($path) || is_file($path)) {
        throw new \LogicException('The provided path must be a readable directory.');
    }

    $files.      = [];
    $directories = scandir($path);

    /*
     * Remove current (.) and parent (..) directory references.
     */
    unset($directories[0], $directories[1]);

    /*
     * Check if the directory is empty after the current and parent
     * directory references has been removed.
     */
    if(empty($directories)) {
        return null;
    }

    foreach($directories as $directory) {

        if(!is_file($directory) && in_array($directory, $ignored)) {
            continue;
        }

        if(!is_file($directory)) {

            $key         = basename($directory); 
            $files[$key] = read_directory_files($directory);

        }else{

            $files[] = $directory;

        }

    }

    return $files;

}
```

**This code is not tested** so an error may occur, but this should make you able to choose which directories you want to read files from. The usage would be:

```
$ignored = [
   'games'
];

$files = read_directory_files('path/to/images', $ignored);
```

If you cannot use your own mechanism to read directories you can TRY to replace the existing code with something like what I have written, but do so at your risk and remember to backup your code.

Hope this can be of any use, happy coding!